# ValueError in multiple input model

Tags: keras, neural-network, functional-programming, conv-neural-network, valueerror

I'm creating a multi input model where i concatenate a CNN model and a LSTM model. The lstm model contains the last 5 events and the CNN contains a picture of the last event. Both are organized so that each element k in the numpy matches the 5 events and the corresponding picture, as do the output labels which is the 'next' event that should be predicted by the model.

```
chanDim = -1
inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
x = inputs
x = Dense(128)(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
```

```
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
```

```
x = Activation("relu")(x)
model_cnn = Model(inputs, x)
```

This creates the CNN model, and the following code represents the LSTM model

```
hidden1 = LSTM(128)(visible)
hidden2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(hidden1)
output = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden2)
model_lstm = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
```

Now, when I combine these models and extend them using a simple dense layer to make the multiclass prediction of 14 classes, all the inputs match and I can concat the (none, 10) and (none, 10) into a (none, 20) for the MLP:

```
x = Dense(14, activation="softmax")(x)
model_mlp = Model(inputs=[model_lstm.input, model_cnn.input], outputs=x)
```

This all works fine until I try to compile the model it gives me an error concerning the input of the last dense layer of the mlp model:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_121 to have shape (14,) but got array with shape (1,)

Do you know how this is possible? If you need more information I'm happy to provide that

Comment: dense_121 is the final layer of the model

Comment: what's the shape of your y_train array? Did you one-hot encode the target?

Comment: The train set for the LSTM is (79322, 1, 5)
The train set for the CNN is (79322, 1, 25088)
The train set for y (outputlabels) is  (113318,)

Comment: I did not one hot encode the numbers but I made categorical ints of the event names from 0 to 14. 0 being the dummy event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your target must be (None, 14) dimensional. with softmax you have to one-hot encode the output

try this:

```
y = pd.get_dummies(np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])).values
y_train = y[:len(y_train)]
y_test = y[len(y_train):]
```

Comment: Do I have to do it for the input values of the LSTM as well? because it is a numpy where each element is an array of the last 5 events. For example (0,0,4,7,2). These events are also the multiclass options for the output (0->14)

Comment: Because I changed the lstm input from (79322,5) to (79322,1,5) with the reshape() function because it expected one extra dimension as input but I'm not sure if it is the same as you are referring to

Comment: the shape of the inputs is not related to your error (I don't know if it's correct and valuable)

Comment: Okay no problem. Thank you so much for your reply!